# iPhone files not showing up on Finder

Tags: iphone, ios, finder

I have an iPhone 11 Pro Max running iOS 13.3 and a Macbook '16 running macOS Catalina 10.15.2.

When I connect my iPhone to my Macbook, it is recognised in Finder "locations" but I do not have access to the files, videos, etc. in the iPhone from within Finder.

I have made sure that my iPhone is "trusted" by the macbook.

What is see is the picture below (and this is the only thing I can see):

[image]

i.e I don't see the following:

[image]

I have no idea why. My iPad works fine and shows me the files, movies, general tab, etc. But not my iPhone.

I have tried the following:

1. Resetting my privacy and location settings on the iPhone. After I do this, I get asked to "trust" the iPhone again, but it still does not display the files.
2. I have restarted the iPhone and Macbook several times.
3. I tried this on iOS 13.2 before updating and it already had this issue, so I don't think it's a bad update problem.
4. I have tried different cables. No luck.
5. I have tried restarting Finder on the Macbook, no luck.
6. The interesting thing is that Photos on the Macbook can detect and load photos from the iPhone.
7. As I said above, my iPad works fine and shows me the files, movies, general tab, etc
8. I made sure the iPhone is unlocked during this whole time.
9. Even if not needed, I made sure that "USB accessories" is allowed access when iPhone is locked inside the "Face ID and passcore" settings menu.
10. Airdrop works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured out whats wrong. See this thread for an answer (TLDR: iTunes database was corrupted) https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4474508

> **DO NOT RESTORE**
>
> - It could be one of two (or both) files are corrupt on your
>     **iPhone** (or other **iDevice**), they are
>     **iTunesDB** and**iTunesCDB**.
> - There
>     is an **fast fix** for this, even if your
>     **iDevice** is **non
>     jailbroken**.
> - You want to disconnect your
>     **iDevice** from your computer and close
>     **iTunes** to ensure you **DO NOT
>     RESTORE**.
> - Download **iFunBox** or
>     **iTools** a Free Tool for accessing the
>     **iDevice** file system. It has both a **OSX
>     version** and **Windows version** for
>     download.
> - After you download the version of
>     **iFunBox** or **iTools** for your OS, you
>     will need to install it and run it.
> - After installing and
>     running **iFunBox** or **iTools**, connect
>     your **iDevice** to your computer.
> - You will see a
>     message in the Upper Right of **iFunBox** ”connecting to
>     **iDevice**“, after **iFunbox** has
>     connected to your **iDevice**, click on the tab
>     “**iFunbox Classic**“.
> - On the left panel, expand
>     “**Raw File System**” (click on the **+**),
>     then expand “**iTunes_Control**“, then click on
>     “**iTunes**“.
> - In the right panel you will see a
>     number of files, **right-click** on the file
>     “**iTunesCDB**” and select rename, please add X after the
>     **iTunesCDB** in the file name, this will allow you keep
>     the file in case you need it again (you should never need it, but
>     better to be careful than sorry.) Do the same for iTunesCDB, iTunesControl and iTunesPrefs.
> - After you have renamed the file, click on your **iDevice** name on the upper right
>     of **iFunBox** and select “**Device Safe
>     Removal**“, this will ensure the file name change will be
>     written back to your **iDevice**.
> - After you see
>     your **iDevice** is closed (“No device connected” will be
>     displayed in the upper right), you should now close
>     **iFunBox**
>
> Now run Apple **iTunes**, it will see your
>   **iDevice** and you will be able to Sync again.